# I need to verify the presence of same element across multiple pages of my application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is I need to check whether a button is present in all the pages I have in my application.

In my first page there are 20 such elements and I took the size and if the size is `> 0` then the test passes. Likewise if I have 5 such pages and the total expected count of elements is 96 then across all the first four pages the count will be 20 and in the last page it will be 16.

I need the total count of all the elements and compare with total count.

I had tried for loop but not working

```
String pageNumberText = objects.pageNum().getText();
String lastWord = pageNumberText.substring(pageNumberText.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
System.out.println(lastWord); int pageNumb = Integer.parseInt(lastWord);
for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumb; i++) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='tgbtn' and @class='tgbtn mainPriceContainer']")));
    System.out.println(pageNumberText);

    List<WebElement> dealBtn = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='tgbtn']/a"));
    if (dealBtn.size() > 0) {
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "Deal button is present");
        System.out.println("Button verification of page " + i + " successful");
        System.out.println("No of deal buttons present are : " + dealBtn.size());
        objects.nextPageBtn().click();
    }
}
```

The result I am getting is even before navigating to next page , the result is getting printed

```
5
1 of 5
Button verification of page 1 successful
No of deal buttons present are : 20
1 of 5
Button verification of page 2 successful
No of deal buttons present are : 20
1 of 5
Button verification of page 3 successful
No of deal buttons present are : 20
1 of 5
Button verification of page 4 successful
No of deal buttons present are : 20
1 of 5
Button verification of page 5 successful
No of deal buttons present are : 20
```

Result is wrong
The no of elements in the last page is 16 only

And the action stops when 2nd page is loaded

Comment: Code is just a text, just copu and the most interesting parts of it here. We hardly can help you whithout the code.

Comment: URL : https://www.kunilexusofgreenwoodvillage.com/

Comment: Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with the wait condition:

```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='tgbtn' and @class='tgbtn mainPriceContainer']")));
```

The thing is this element is present on each of your pages, so when you click on "NextPageBtn" the condition is met right away, and execution won't wait until the next page is actually loaded, so all of the 5 executions happen very quick before loading the next page, all the (20) results are results from the first page.

What you should try is wait until the number of the current page in the pagination element equals `i`, or something like that which indicates that you have actually reached the page that your loop expects you to be at.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I can add two points to fix your code:
1) If you need to get count as '96' at the end of loop, declare `List<WebElement> dealBtn` outside for loop, create another same type of variable inside for loop and assign `List<WebElement>` returned by this `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='tgbtn']/a"))` to that local variable. Later using for loop or some other Collections concept, append local `List<WebElement>` elements into the global variable 'dealBtn'. By this way, we can get total count 96 at the end of for loop.

2) Waiting for an element:
The first line in for loop will try to wait until visibility of element. Hence, you can add another wait condition inside if statement after `objects.nextPageBtn().click();` to wait invisibility of the same element using 'invisibilityOfElementLocated()'. By this way once you clicked on nextPageButton(), it will wait until the element to be invisible. Once page gets started reloading, element will get disappear from DOM and that wait condition will be satisfied. Later it will go for 2nd round of the loop and wait until the page contains that element in the DOM. Like this way, same execution will be repeated until the loop gets terminated....

By combining these two cases, Hope your scripts will be executed on all the 5 pages and at the end, you will get total elements count as 96 (Print total count outside for loop)

Try this code:

```
String pageNumberText = objects.pageNum().getText();
        String lastWord = pageNumberText.substring(pageNumberText.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
        System.out.println(lastWord); int pageNumb = Integer.parseInt(lastWord);
        List<WebElement> dealBtn = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageNumb; i++) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='tgbtn' and @class='tgbtn mainPriceContainer']")));
            System.out.println(pageNumberText);

            List<WebElement> localData= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='tgbtn']/a"));
        for(int index= 0; index < localData.size(); i++) {
            dealBtn.add(localData.get(index));
        }
            if (dealBtn.size() > 0) {
                Assert.assertTrue(true, "Deal button is present");
                System.out.println("Button verification of page " + i + " successful");
                System.out.println("No of deal buttons present in page-" + i + " are : " + localData.size());
                objects.nextPageBtn().click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='tgbtn' and @class='tgbtn mainPriceContainer']")));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total elements in all the pages are : " + dealBtn .size());
```